# Get sorted queryset by specified field with regex in django

Tags: python, regex, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have the following in Manager:

```
class NullIf(Func):
template = "NULLIF(%(expressions)s, '')"

class MySiteManager(models.Manager):

def get_queryset(self):
    qws = MySiteQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db).filter(
        some_id=settings.BASE_SOME_ID).annotate(
            # This is made for sorting by short labels as by numeric values
            short_label_numeric=Cast(
                NullIf(Func(
                    F('short_label'),
                    Value('^(\D+)|(\w+)'),
                    Value(''),
                    Value('g'),
                    function='regexp_replace')),
                models.BigIntegerField())
            ).order_by('short_label_numeric', 'short_label')

    for q in qws:
        print(q.short_label, end='\n')

    return qws
```

Output of print values looks like:

1
10
100
101
102
103
104
105
106
107
108
109
11
110
111
112
113
114
115
116
117
118
119
12
120
121
122
123
124
125
126
127
128
129
13
130
131
132
133
134
135
136
137
138
139
14
140
141
142
143
144
145
146
147
148
149
15
150
151
152
153
154
155
156
157
158
159
16
17
18
19
20
200c
21
22
23
24
25
26
260
261
262
263
264
265fs
266fs
267c
268c
269c
27
273c
274c
275c
276c
28
29
2c
30
302
31
32c
33c
34
35c
36
37
38
3c
4
5
501
502
503
504
505
506
507
508
509
510
511
512
513
514
515
516
517
518
519
520
521
522
524
6
601
602
603
604
605
606
607
608
609
610
611
612
613
614
615
616
617
618
619
620
621
622
623
7
701
702
703
704
705
706
707
708
709
710
8
801
802
803
804
805
806
807
808
809
810
9
901
902
S1
S10
S11
S12
S13
S14
S15
S16
S17
S18
S19
S2
S20
S3
S4
S5
S6
S7
S8
S9

And my question:
How to build queryset with output looks like e.g. 1 2 3 3c 4 5 6 6c ... 264 265fs 266fs 267c 268c 269c ... S1 S2 S3 S4 ??? Does someone have any assumptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the main idea is order by numeric and then by char part of the label, i can't reproduce and test, but solution may looks like:

first here the sql:

```
SELECT 
  (regexp_matches(short_label, '^\d+'))[1]::numeric AS ln,
  regexp_matches(short_label, '^\D+') as ls,
  short_label
FROM YOUR_APP_TABLENAME ORDER BY 1, 2, 3;
```

annotaion in the orm:

for first sql condition i create [custom Func](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions)

```
In [1]: from myapp.models import *

In [2]: from django.db.models import F, Func, Value
   ...: 
   ...: class StartNumeric(Func):
   ...:     function = 'REGEXP_MATCHES'
   ...:     template = "(%(function)s(%(expressions)s, '^\d+'))[1]::int"
   ...: 
   ...: qs = Ingredient.objects.annotate(
   ...:     ln=StartNumeric('short_label'),
   ...:     ls=Func('short_label', Value('^\D+'), function='regexp_matches'),
   ...:     ).values('ln').order_by('ln', 'ls', 'short_label')
   ...: 
   ...:     

In [3]: print(qs.query)
SELECT (REGEXP_MATCHES("myapp_ingredient"."short_label", '^\d+'))[1]::int AS "ln" FROM "myapp_ingredient" ORDER BY "ln" ASC, regexp_matches("myapp_ingredient"."short_label", ^\D+) ASC, "myapp_ingredient"."short_label" ASC

In [4]: data = qs.values_list('short_label', flat=True)
   ...: print(list(data))
   ...: 
   ...: 
['1', '2c', '3c', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32c', '33c', '34', '35c', '36', '37', '38', '100', '101', '102', '103', '104', '105', '106', '107', '108', '109', '110', '111', '112', '113', '114', '115', '116', '117', '118', '119', '120', '121', '122', '123', '124', '125', '126', '127', '128', '129', '130', '131', '132', '133', '134', '135', '136', '137', '138', '139', '140', '141', '142', '143', '144', '145', '146', '147', '148', '149', '150', '151', '152', '153', '154', '155', '156', '157', '158', '159', '200c', '260', '261', '262', '263', '264', '265fs', '266fs', '267c', '268c', '269c', '273c', '274c', '275c', '276c', '302', '501', '502', '503', '504', '505', '506', '507', '508', '509', '510', '511', '512', '513', '514', '515', '516', '517', '518', '519', '520', '521', '522', '524', '601', '602', '603', '604', '605', '606', '607', '608', '609', '610', '611', '612', '613', '614', '615', '616', '617', '618', '619', '620', '621', '622', '623', '701', '702', '703', '703', '704', '705', '706', '707', '708', '709', '710', '801', '802', '803', '804', '805', '806', '807', '808', '809', '810', '901', '902', 'aaaa', 'ddd', 'ddeee', 'rrrrr', 'S1', 'S10', 'S11', 'S12', 'S13', 'S14', 'S15', 'S16', 'S17', 'S18', 'S19', 'S2', 'S20', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5', 'S6', 'S7', 'S8', 'S9', 'vvvv', 'zzzz']
```

hope it help

Answer (score 1):

How about sorting the output using a [natural sort](https://blog.codinghorror.com/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order/):

```
import re
_nsre = re.compile(r'(\d+)')
def natural_sort_key(s):
    return [int(text) if text.isdigit() else text.lower()
            for text in re.split(_nsre, s)]

s = "1 10 2 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 11 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 12 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 13 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 14 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 15 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 16 17 18 19 20 200c 21 22 23 24 25 26 260 261 262 263 264 265fs 266fs 267c 268c 269c 27 273c 274c 275c 276c 28 29 2c 30 302 31 32c 33c 34 35c 36 37 38 3c 4 5 501 502 503 504 505 506 507 508 509 510 511 512 513 514 515 516 517 518 519 520 521 522 524 6 601 602 603 604 605 606 607 608 609 610 611 612 613 614 615 616 617 618 619 620 621 622 623 7 701 702 703 704 705 706 707 708 709 710 8 801 802 803 804 805 806 807 808 809 810 9 901 902 S1 S10 S11 S12 S13 S14 S15 S16 S17 S18 S19 S2 S20 S3 S4 S5 S6 S7 S8 S9"
list1 = s.split(' ')
list1.sort(key=natural_sort_key)
```

Output `list1`:

```
['1',  '2',  '2c',  '3c',  '4',  '5',  '6',  '7',  '8',  '9',  '10',  '11',  '12',  '13',  '14',  '15',  '16',  '17',  '18',  '19',  '20',  '21',  '22',  '23',  '24',  '25',  '26',  '27',  '28',  '29',  '30',  '31',  '32c',  '33c',  '34',  '35c',  '36',  '37',  '38',  '100',  '101',  '102',  '103',  '104',  '105',  '106',  '107',  '108',  '109',  '110',  '111',  '112',  '113',  '114',  '115',  '116',  '117',  '118',  '119',  '120',  '121',  '122',  '123',  '124',  '125',  '126',  '127',  '128',  '129',  '130',  '131',  '132',  '133',  '134',  '135',  '136',  '137',  '138',  '139',  '140',  '141',  '142',  '143',  '144',  '145',  '146',  '147',  '148',  '149',  '150',  '151',  '152',  '153',  '154',  '155',  '156',  '157',  '158',  '159',  '200c',  '260',  '261',  '262',  '263',  '264',  '265fs',  '266fs',  '267c',  '268c',  '269c',  '273c',  '274c',  '275c',  '276c',  '302',  '501',  '502',  '503',  '504',  '505',  '506',  '507',  '508',  '509',  '510',  '511',  '512',  '513',  '514',  '515',  '516',  '517',  '518',  '519',  '520',  '521',  '522',  '524',  '601',  '602',  '603',  '604',  '605',  '606',  '607',  '608',  '609',  '610',  '611',  '612',  '613',  '614',  '615',  '616',  '617',  '618',  '619',  '620',  '621',  '622',  '623',  '701',  '702',  '703',  '704',  '705',  '706',  '707',  '708',  '709',  '710',  '801',  '802',  '803',  '804',  '805',  '806',  '807',  '808',  '809',  '810',  '901',  '902',  'S1',  'S2',  'S3',  'S4',  'S5',  'S6',  'S7',  'S8',  'S9',  'S10',  'S11',  'S12',  'S13',  'S14',  'S15',  'S16',  'S17',  'S18',  'S19',  'S20']
```

Comment: Your approach easier and so good for using. Preferably for my case to use "re.split(_nsre, s.short_label)" instead "re.split(_nsre, s)" cause I working with list of objects)) Thanks alot for your solution @wp78de !)