# Searching a keyword with number of occurence in django

Tags: django, search

I want o search for a keyword from the descriptions field with an exact number of occurrences in Django.

suppose I am searching the keyword 'Balam' with the number of occurrence '5 times'. what will be the query?

if the searching keyword 'Balam' query is :

```
filter(descriptions__icontains='Balam')
```

what will be the query for searching 'Balam' with the exact occurence '5 times'?

Answer (score 0):

That's a task at the database level, so it will depend which platform you're on.

Assuming that you're using postgresql, you have access to the REGEXP_MATCHES function.  Django's [`Func`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions) allows you to use any database function in the ORM (see [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59250808/9461432) here), so you could annotate regexp_matches, and then filter on the results.