# Django use StrIndex to get the last instance of a character for an annotation

Tags: sql, django

I have a model with a key that's value is a file path, ie `/src/code/foo`. I need the file name so I want to get the sub string of `foo` for my annotation value. The logical way I was aiming to go about it was to get the index of the last `/` character. I was trying to do this via `StrIndex` & `Substr` but `StrIndex` only gives me the first index. Is there a way I can get the last index instead?

```py
MyModel.objects.all().annotate(
  # this would give me `src/code/foo` but I want just `foo`
  name=Cast(Substr("file_path", StrIndex("file_path", V("/"))), TextField())
)
```

Comment: I think writing custom function and using regex there is the easiest solution, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50645204/get-sorted-queryset-by-specified-field-with-regex-in-django

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to reverse the string in order to get the last occurence, but then you can use that with Right to get the tail.  Subtracting 1 to get rid of the / itself from the string.

```py
from django.db.models.functions import StrIndex, Reverse, Right
from django.db.models import CharField, F

MyModel.annotate(
    last_occur=StrIndex(Reverse('file_path'), Value('/')),
    name=Right('file_path', F('last_occur')-1, output_field=CharField())
)
```

You could do it all as a single annotation, with `StrIndex` within `Right`, but I think it's easier to follow with the steps separated out like this.

Comment: Worked flawlessly. Thank you!